# How to check for a running shell in windows?

Tags: python, shell, security, cmd, subprocess

I try to write a programm in python that notifies me, when a shell like cmd gets opened.

Until now I did the following in python.
Check for new starting processes, get the name of the process and check if its name is cmd.exe.
This works if I start a cmd process manually myself.

But it Turns out if i open a shell with **subprocess.getoutput(command)** from the subprocess library in python there is no shell listed in the prosesses and I also cant see it in taskmanager.
So I assumed its a childprocess of the pythonscripts process running?

My next Idea was to list all the modules a process is using and check for cmd.exe in the modules.
It turns out the pythonscript with subprocess.getoutput(command) does not use cmd.exe in the modules. Strange.

So right now I am not sure how I could detect the shell or if I am even on the right way.
Maybe I need to find the childprocesses of a the pythonprocess? Or is it possible to get a shell without calling cmd.exe I honestly dont know enough about it.
Maybe its better to check for chertain dlls in the used methods by a process?

I also tried to look in the subprocess.py library but it is difficult for me to understand and it seems to atleast pass over cmd as a parameter for subprocess.getoutput() method.

Can somebody help?

Thank you.

UPDATE:

I use this code to detect the process:

```
import wmi

c = wmi.WMI()
process_watcher = c.Win32_Process.watch_for("creation")
while True:
    new_process = process_watcher()
    print(new_process.Caption, new_process.ProcessId)
    if new_process.Caption =="cmd.exe":
        pid = new_process.ProcessID
        break
```

But if I run this code

```
import subprocess
output = subprocess.getoutput("ipconfig")
print(output)
```

The only process detected is pythonw.exe

But if I run

```
import subprocess
while True:
    output = subprocess.getoutput("ipconfig")
    print(output)
```

At some point it find cmd.exe.

So I assume that wmi takes to long to detect the process. So cmd is already closed and does not get found.

Any Ideas how to do this a better way?

Comment: @user3763507: What does it mean that _cmd gets **opened**_?

Comment: @user1934428 I guess I mean the execution of cmd. Sorry if dont use the right terminology. I will be happy if you teach me more.

Comment: @user3762507 : So you want to know, if on your system a `cmd. exe` is running? Isn't Task Manager or Process Explorer exactly doing this?

Comment: [Here](https://superuser.com/questions/1231640/how-to-search-a-process-by-name)  is a solution. It is in Powershell, but you can execute a powershell script from your Python program.

Answer (score 0):

I didnt know practic version of solution.But you can use pyautogui for it if you want.You can write a program with pyautogui that notifies you when it find cmd logo at task bar.Example:

```
import pyautogui
cmdlogo = pyautogui.locateOnScreen('get screenshot of cmd logo and write file name here example:'cmd.png'')
While True:
    if cmdlogo:
        print('write here what yo want to say when it finds cmd')
    else:
        pyautogui.sleep(5)
```

Comment: Thanks for your asnswer. I guess usually the GUI will not show up. I am looking for a different solution.